# python dataframe grouping separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I want to control dataframe in a specific way.

if there is a group of dfs
(mostly devided by using 'for' function)
like

```
df1 = iris.iloc[ : , 0:1]
df2 = iris.iloc[ : , 1:2]
.
.
.
dfn = iris.iloc[ : , n-1:n]
```

I want to group dfs like

```
df_group1 = df1, df2, ...., dfn
df_group2 = df1, df3, ...., df(n-1)
```

First, I do not want to do this manually.

Second, I do not want to use tuple, dictionary, or list; temporal usage is possible in process of grouping, but the end result should not be tuple, dictionary, or list. This is because I want to use df_group in other functions as well

Third, combining the dataframes is not the point of this question.

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind your grouping?

Comment: Oh... that is the point of the question actually. I want to know the type of logic (coding) that I should establish in order to group like above.

Comment: I just want to group each df in a seperate and specific (like above) manner.

df_group1> can be grouping all df column sperately

df_group2> can be grouping all even colum of iris df sperately

Comment: The logic of the each grouping may change. However, I do not want them to be grouped in tuple, dictionarly, or list.